# Incorrect plot from a pandas Series with datetimes indeces

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

When I use matplotlib to plot a pandas Series containing three float values with indices that are datetimes, I get a incorrect plot with a vertical line in the middle. It looks like this:

[image: strange vertical line]

I've been struggling with this for hours. I'm finally able to reproduce it with these three data points in the following Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = """\
2013-04-16 08:50:00.080120 / 56.70999
2013-04-16 08:53:34.165183 / 56.59997
2013-04-16 08:59:09.676249 / 55.70001\
"""

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
val = [float(a.split(' / ')[1]) for a in data.split('\n')]
indx = [pd.datetime.strptime(a.split(' / ')[0], fmt) for a in data.split('\n')]

s = pd.Series(val, index=indx)

s.plot()
plt.show()
```

If I zoom in on the line I can see it's placed, seemingly, at the correct date (April 16), but at exactly midnight, instead of at the times specified by the data (and echoed by `print`ing `s`).

Comment: by the way: it's not a problem of `show`, but of pandas. Would be better to change the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of matplotlib and pandas are you using?

With pandas `v0.10.1.dev-f73128e` and matplotlib `v1.2.1`  I get the correct figure whether I do the plot in Ipython in interactive mode or from a python script. (btw I use python 2.7)

[image: figure]

Comment: Thanks! It must have been a bug in the pandas version that ships with Ubuntu Quantal (0.8.0-2). I just installed 0.10.1 from the tarball and I get the correct figure now.

Comment: perfect then. For your info: at the moment on Raring the 0.10.1 version of pandas is shipped